# Edge weight function for graph instance of scheduling and allocation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I have difficulties developing a proper (non-scalar) edge cost function $c_e$ for my resource scheduling problem, which I mapped into a graph problem.

Processes $P_i$ need resources $R_i \in \mathcal{R}$. Since there is a fixed amount of resources, we can depict the requirements of a given process $p$ as vector
$v_p \in \mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{R}|}$.

Each node of the graph is a process $p$ with his corresponding $v_p$.

For
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline & R_0 & R_1 & R_2 \\
\hline P_0 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
\hline P_1 & 3 & 3 & 2\\
\hline
\end{array}
$ we have $ v_{p_0} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
2\\
1
\end{array}
\right)$ 
and 
$ v_{p_1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\
3\\
2
\end{array}
\right)
$

- $v_{p_1}-v_{p_0} = \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  1\\
  1
  \end{array}
  \right)$ means we can switch from $p_1$ to $p_0$ without allocating new resources, we even have excess of $3 = \| v_{p_1}-v_{p_0} \|_1$. One has $p_0 \subseteq p_1$ (You can't use the manhatten norm if the components of the difference vector are positive and negative).
- $v_{p_0}-v_{p_1} = \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  -1\\
  -1\\
  -1
  \end{array}
  \right)$ means, if we want to switch from $p_0$ to $p_1$, we have to allocate one of each resource type.

Based on this model, I would like to derive a cost function for the edges, so that I can search for an optimal hamilton circle on the resulting graph (e. g. TSP) to get a path consisting all vertices, i. e. a optimal execution sequence for the processes with minimum allocation cost.

---

I thought of a function $c: (P, P) \rightarrow (\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}^{-})$ that returns a tuple with total excess and total deficit. But a tuple as edge weight seems kind of unfamiliar to me. Currently I'm experimenting with vector metrics, e.g. dot product and trying to find a reasonable use there. But it's not that easy.

I would be glad about some comments, ideas or solutions.

---

**Motivation**

- [Development of algorithmical concept for scheduling and allocation problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201802/development-of-algorithmical-concept-for-scheduling-and-allocation-problem)
- [Create theoretical model for scheduling and allocation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424536/create-theoretical-model-for-scheduling-and-allocation-problem) (not updated yet)

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it. I'm favoring the idea of using the difference vector $d_{p_x,p_y} = v_{p_x}-v_{p_y}$ as edge weight.

If I define a total order on these vectors, the algorithms I want to apply have a mean to choose the *minimum/maximum* edge.

Also no information is lost (It also wouldn't be lost, if I had a bijective weight function $c(e) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ or $c(e) \rightarrow (\mathbb{N},~\mathbb{Z}^{-})$).